# A few applications are automatically opened when I first turn on the mac

Tags: macos

I have a few applications that are automatically opened when I start the computer, for example TextWrangler or Activity Monitor. Is it possible to start the computer without this stupid behaviour?

Answer (score 4):

Either these apps were running when you turned off the Mac and you are have selected to 'Reopen windows when logging back in' on the log off or shutdown dialog, or you have these apps listed in the Login Items list available from System Preferences → Users & Groups.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not using TextWrangler so much, but assuming this old one picture, I can deduct that it had got ***startup action***, which was removed in future versions. *But value in property list is still remains*. So you can try this `defaults write com.barebones.textwrangler StartupAndResumeAction 0`. Hope this may help you

[image: textWrangler preferences]

Comment: Checking this last checkbox would cause open-at-startup _only_ if documents were open at the time textWrangler was quit - not any time the computer is started up.

Comment: Thank you, @IconDaemon, I didn't get this. Otherwise, eventually I disable launch at startup searching in launch folders. And hope that this could help